# Как удалить объект класса из списка обьектов класса python

Tags: python, ооп

Для изучения классов пишу игру жизнь на питон. Столкнулся с непонятной мне ошибкой при описании смерти(т.е удаления объекта класса из списка классов). В некоторых случаях код отрабатывает правильно и все объекты класса удаляются верно при достижении счетчиком значения. Но иногда выполнение скрипта прерывается на строке l[i].show с ошибкой IndexError: list index out of range. В чем моя ошибка и как это исправить? Код привожу ниже.

```
import random
import time


class cat(object):
    def __init__(self):
        name_male=['Tom','Alex','Bob','Liam','Noah','Mason','Ethan','Logan','Lucas','Jackson','Aiden','Oliver','Elijah','Alexander','James']
        name_female=['Emma','Olivia','Ava','Sophia','Isabella','Mia','Charlotte','Amelia','Emily','Madison','Harper','Abigail','Avery']
        male=['male', 'female']
        male=random.choice(male)
        age=random.randrange(1,20)

        if male=='male':
            name=random.choice(name_male)
        else:
            name=random.choice(name_female)
        self.name=name
        self.male=male
        self.age=age


    def show(self):
        print('-------')
        print('Имя:',self.name)
        print('Пол:',self.male)
        print('возраст:',self.age)
        print('-------')
    def __del__(self):
        print(self.name,"удален из памяти")



l=[]
count_cats=random.randrange(1,10)
print('количество котов  в популяции:',count_cats)

for i in range (count_cats):
        l.append(cat())
while len(l)!=0:
    for i in range(len(l)):
            print(i)
            l[i].show()
            l[i].age+=1

            if l[i].age>20:
                    del l[i]
                    input()
    print('*****************************************')
print(len(l))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл `for i in range(len(l)):` не знает, что длина списка уменьшилась из-за удаления элемента.

Выход - удалять **с конца списка** или использовать цикл while, который будет постоянно опрашивать текущую длину.

```
for i in range(len(l)-1, -1, -1):
```

Comment: ```@MBo``` исправил код следующим образом :```                                                                     
 while lena!=0:
    for i in range(lena):
            l[i].show()
            l[i].age+=1

            if l[i].age>20:
                    del l[i]
                    lena-=1``` результата не получил ошибка та же

Comment: Пределы цикла for рассчитываются один раз, поэтому такое изменение ничего не поменяло. Добавил пример

Comment: ```@MBo``` это работает спасибо, я конечно уже Вам надоел, но обьясните пожалуйста как декрементация помогла решить проблему ?

Comment: В таком случае цикл идет вниз, и не проходит по индексам уже убитых элементов, они остаются выше